# Is it possible to not show extra box by default when Allowed number of values is Unlimited in Text (formatted, long, with summary)?

Tags: nodes, 9

I have created a **long text formatted** field with **unlimited** allowed number of values. But it is giving one extra box as default.

[image: box]

Every time user edits the content the empty box will show. That is so annoying. Second box should be appear only when I click on **Add another item**

Case1: (first edit)
[image]

Case2: (second edit)
[image]

It is creating issue after second edit. Anyone have any idea that How can I make this field act properly?